# Get rid of "Dynamic Text font size are unsupported" Warnings within Accessibility Inspector

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile, accessibility

I want to ask you - does anyone know how to get rid of the "Dynamic Text font sizes are unsupported" Warnings within Accessibility Inspector for iOS ?

I got a React Native application, I've disabled Font Scaling globally by overriding defaultProps (allowFontScalling: false) for Text and TextInput, but I still receive "Dynamic Text font sizes are unsupported" Warnings in the Accessibility Inspector that I use on the iOS Simulator.

How can I get rid of these Warnings I receive for TextInputs ? I can confirm that font is no longer scalable after doing that override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is the exact opposite of what you think it means. The entire error message is:

> "Issue: Dynamic Text font sizes are unsupported. **User will not be able to change the font size of this element**"

The last part is the important bit, what you have done means that a user cannot set the font size they prefer / require (which is an accessibility fail).

You should allow font sizes to be changed according to system preferences and so `allowFontScaling` should be set to `true` and your layout should adapt / be able to accommodate larger font sizes.

This is important for people with vision impairments in order to be able to use your App.

Comment: I am aware that text scaling is important for people with vision impairments. Thing is, even if allowFontScaling is set to true, I still get the Warnings (and yes, you can change text size within Settings - tried it). I don't know what is causing these Warnings for inputs on iOS.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting `allowFontScaling` on the input itself just to check it isn't being overridden somewhere? Also how are you setting the font size on the inputs, have you used a fixed unit? Sorry I am not overly familiar with react-native.

Comment: Yes, I've set allowFontScaling={true} and tried with both - having and not having a fontSize set for the inputs. As for changing the font size, I've done it through the Accessibility Inspector on the iOS Simulator. Still getting these Warnings - "Dynamic Text font sizes are unsupported" (User will not be able to change the font size of this RCTUITextField) - even if I can change the font size in the options there in Accessibility Inspector (I see text increasing in the inputs) - which is weird.

Comment: Anyone got solution for this?